# Tweepy not crawling full text (Tweets)- missing part of the text

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy, tweets

We are trying to crawl tweets using Tweepy. but we are not getting full tweets. Could you please look into code below and advise?

```
auth = tw.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tw.API(auth)

new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'sdrumm',count=200, tweet_mode="extended")


search_words = "trump+US"
date_since = "2020-01-30"
new_search = search_words + " -filter:retweets"
new_search


tweets1 = tw.Cursor(api.search,
          q=new_search1,
          lang="en",
          since=date_since).items(500)
    tweets1
    for tweet1 in tweets1:
    print(tweet1.text)
```

**Results**
Below is one of the tweets which we get

"@piersmorgan why has colloidal silver been tested on the coronavirus because they have used it for ebola mrsa and s… URLhttps:......

Whereas the original tweet is given below

"@piersmorgan why has colloidal silver been tested on the coronavirus because they have used it for ebola mrsa and swine flu as I have used it on mrsa and swine flu and caterax and it worked"

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/tweet-updates go into `extended` mode. Then you can access an attribtue called `full_text`

Comment: Thanks but I am already into extended mode

new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'sdrumm',count=200, tweet_mode="extended")

pls correct me if I am doing any mistake? or where I should do changes?

Comment: Your `Cursor` is not in `tweet_mode='extended'`. `new_tweets` is irrelevant. You defined it but didn't use it in the shown code again.

Comment: @TinNguyen Thanks again. sorry I am new into it. Could you pls help me what to change in my code? appreciate that

Comment: @TinNguyen

tweets1 = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=new_search1, tweet_mode="extended",
              lang="en",
              since=date_since).items(500)
tweets1
for tweet1 in tweets1:
    print(tweet1.full_text)

is it fine now?